# Fetch query result into cursor within procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm migrating many procedures from MySQL to oracle and I've found some issues. This is what I've got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(PROCEDURE_PARAM IN NUMBER)
IS
CURSOR C1 (CURSOR_PARAMETER IN NUMBER)
IS
 SELECT COL1, COL2, MY_FUNCTION1(P1), SUM(COL3), MY_FUNCTION2(P1,P2)
        COL4, MY_FUNCTION(P1,P2,P3,P4)
 FROM TABLE_1
 WHERE COL1 = CURSOR_PARAMETER -- How to reference it to 'Procedure_param' ?
 GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL4
 ORDER BY COL2;

BEGIN
    -- HOW TO FETCH RESULTS INTO CURSOR ??
END PROCEDURE1;
/
```

Those are an example of name columns and functions(user created functions). My concerns are how to tell the cursor that the parameter `CURSOR_PARAMETER` is the same of `PROCEDURE_PARAM` and also the most important, how to fetch the results  into the cursor?
I'm stuck in this problem. Any help would be appreciated. With this example I could start converting all procedures I have to.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd fetch from the cursor like :

```
BEGIN
  for r_row in C1(PROCEDURE_PARAM)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_row.col1);--or whatever you want to do here.
  end loop;
end;
```

though i usually prefer to write these inline as

```
begin
  for r_row in (SELECT COL1, COL2, MY_FUNCTION1(P1), 
                       SUM(COL3), MY_FUNCTION2(P1,P2)
                       COL4, MY_FUNCTION(P1,P2,P3,P4)
                  FROM TABLE_1
                 WHERE COL1 = PROCEDURE_PARAM 
                 GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL4
                 ORDER BY COL2)
  loop
    ...
  end loop;
```

just so I don't have to scroll up to a cursor def to see what it was actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more question. How do I "return" (i know it is a procedure not a function) the fetched cursor. What should i do between loop and end loop statements ?

Comment: @AlejandroBastidas a `CURSOR` isn't returnable, they are only designed to be used within the program unit they are opened within. to return a resultset, you have to use a ref cursor. see: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php  you can then return this as an OUT parameter in a procedure or as a function return